# Selecting data from different tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table of articles defined by their `ID`, `name`, `price` and `category_ID` and a table of categories defined by `category_ID` and `name`.
I want to select into my controller, the list of articles, along with the category `name`.

How to do that?

Comment: are you using Eloquent?

Comment: you have to define Eloquent relationships in your models

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you keep the models in App\Models folder

In your Articles model define the following method.

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}
```

You can access it now via `$myArticle->category->name;`

Make sure in Categories model the correct table is defined, based on your question i can not make up the categorie table.

Put `$table = 'categories';` in the category model or whatever the table name is.

Comment: Note that $myArticle->category() (called as method) returns a Query Builder object, therefore you cannot access name property. You should call the relationship as a property instead and to avoid the N+1 queries, eager load the relation before looping thorough articles.

Comment: A last note is that you could refer to the related model with `Category::class`. As long as the Category model (file) is in the same directory as the Post model, it would resolve to the correct class as well as typing the FQDN as a string. In addition you would also get IDEs completion/refactoring support.

Answer (score 0):

with raw `SQL`

```
$query = "SELECT articles.* , categories.name AS categoryName FROM articles JOIN categories ON articles.category_ID = categories. category_ID"
$result = \DB::select(SQL);
dump($result)
```

**or**

with `Eloquent` you can add a method to your model to return relationship , let's call it `category`

```
class Article extends Model {
    public function category(){ 
        return $this->hasOne("App/Category" , "category_ID" , "category_ID");
    }
}
```

now you can do this

```
$article = Article::find(1);
dump($article->category->name);
```

checkout [`hasOne`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) method from the docs